# Can't get my code to repeat the questions for the game to continue

Tags: java, while-loop, do-while

I have to write a code for my class I'm taking.  It is a game based on betting on 2 colors and numbers from 1 - 36.  The user has a set amount of chips already given to them which is 100.  I have already written most of the code, however, I can't get my code to repeat the process.  I am currently using a Do-While loop. but it just isn't working.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;

public class Program_8 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        int chipsNow = 100;
        int userChoice;
        int chipsBetted = 0;
        
        
        //welcome message
        welcome();  
        
        do {
            
            
            int spinNum = (int)(Math.random() * 36) + 0;
            userChoice = getMenuChoice(userInput);
            
            //get user choice
            if (userChoice == 1) {
                int getNum = getNumber(userInput);
                int getBet = getBet(userInput, chipsNow);
                String determineColor = determineColor(spinNum);
                
                System.out.println("\nSpinning Wheel....");
                System.out.println("Spin Number: " + spinNum);
                System.out.println("Spin Color: " + determineColor);
                
                if (getNum == spinNum) {
                    
                    chipsNow += getBet;
                    chipsBetted += getBet;
                    System.out.println("Congrats, you won!");
                    System.out.println("\nYou now have: " + chipsNow + " chips");
                    ;
                }
                
                else {
                    chipsNow -= getBet;
                    
                    System.out.println("\nSorry, you lost!");
                    System.out.println("You now have: " + chipsNow + " chips");
                    
                }
            }
            
            if (userChoice == 2) {
                String getColor = getColor(userInput);
                int getBet = getBet(userInput, chipsNow);
                String determineColor = determineColor(spinNum);
                
                System.out.println("Spinning Wheel....");
                System.out.println("Spin Number: " + spinNum);
                System.out.println("Spin Color: " + determineColor);
                
                if (getColor.equals(determineColor)) {
                    
                    chipsNow += getBet;
                    chipsBetted += getBet;
                    System.out.println("\nCongrats, you won!");
                    System.out.println("You now have: " + chipsNow + " chips");
                    
                }
                
                else {
                    
                    chipsNow -= getBet;
                    System.out.println("\nSorry, you lost!");
                    System.out.println("You now have: " + chipsNow + " chips");
                    
                    }
                }
                
        }while (userChoice != 3 && chipsNow > 0);
        
        
        
    }
    
    //welcome message
    public static void welcome() {
        
        int chipsNow = 100;
        
        System.out.println("############################");
        System.out.println("#    Welcome To Roulette   #");
        System.out.println("############################");
        System.out.println("# Number Bets Payout: 35:1 #");
        System.out.println("# Color Bets Payout: 1:1   #");
        System.out.println("############################\n");
        System.out.println("Chips owned: " + chipsNow + "\n");
        
        System.out.println("1. Pick a number to bet on");
        System.out.println("2. Pick a color to bet on");
        System.out.println("3. Cash Out\n");
        
    }
    //get menu choice
    public static int getMenuChoice(Scanner userInput) {
        int getMenuChoice;
        
        System.out.println("\nChoose an option [1-3]: ");
        getMenuChoice = userInput.nextInt();
        
        
        return getMenuChoice;
    }
    
    public static int getNumber(Scanner userInput) {
        int getNumber;
        
        do {
            
        System.out.println("Enter a number to bet on [0-36]: ");
        getNumber = userInput.nextInt();
        
        
        }while (getNumber < 0 || getNumber > 36);   
        
        
        return getNumber;
    }
    
    public static String getColor(Scanner userInput) {
        String getColor = "";
        
        do{
        System.out.println("Enter a color to bet on [Red or Black]: ");
        getColor = userInput.next();
        
        }while (!(getColor.equals("Red") || getColor.equals("Black")));
                
        return getColor;
    }
    
    public static int getBet(Scanner userInput, int chipsNow) {
        int getBet;
        
        do{
        System.out.println("Enter the number of chips to bet [1 - " + chipsNow + "]: ");
        getBet = userInput.nextInt();
        
        }while (getBet < 1 || getBet > chipsNow);
        
        
        return getBet;
    }
    
    public static String determineColor(int spinNum) {
        
        if (spinNum % 2 == 0) {
            if (spinNum == 0) {
                return "Green";
            }
            //even
            else {
                return "Red";
            }
        }
        
        return "Black";
        
        
    }
    
    public static void report(int chipsNow) {
        
        System.out.println("\nThanks for Playing!");
        System.out.println("You Won a total of: " + chipsNow + " chips today");
        
        
        
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So just looking at the code I'd:

1. Declare `int userChoice = 0;` outside the do while. This is needed for the while condition to work.
2. `welcome();` and `userChoice = getMenuChoice(userInput);` should move into the do while thus it will repeat the welcome message and ask for a user choice everything the do while executes
3. Simplify your while loop like this `while(userChoice != 3 && chipsNow > 0)`. This is just to make it more readable.
4. Lastly remove the `break;`s in your `if(getNum == spinNum) { } else { }`. A `break` will force the while loop to be exited regardless of whether the while condition is met. So basically if you win or lose a game your loop will exit, which I don't think is what you want. You only want the loop to exit if the `chipsNow < 0` or the `userChoice == 3`

Comment: Yes only the one outside should have the `int` part the other in the while loop shouldn't have this.

Comment: yeah i just noticed that, thanks for the quick reply

Comment: You are declaring the userChoice by doing `int userChoice = 0;` afterwards in the while loop you should just do `userChoice = ....;` notice in the second one I don't use int as its already been declared outside of the while loop

Comment: No problem mate, hope it works if so please do give an upvote and mark as solved if it is.

Comment: The life of a developer 

Comment: yeah my last thing is to, use my report() functions to determine how many chips were won after the player cashes out.  Which I'm having trouble figuring out.  It's my first time using java afterall

Comment: Whats the problem looking at the code it looks fine if they player started with 100 chips and won 1 game and then cashed out i assume it would show 100 plus how ever many chips they won?

Comment: The only issue I can see is i can't see where you add the number of chips won to `chipsNow` you only ever minus the chips bet never do you add the chips they won

Comment: i did switch it up a bit to make the chipsNow += getBet instead of having it subtract from chipsNow.  Instead of outputting 100 + the amount of chips won, I want it to just spit out the amount won,  So if the user bets and wins, then cashes out it will output what the user won instead.  Right now I added another variable called chipsBetted which is working right now.  Let me update my code

Comment: Well id assume you only must add when they win ... your code was right when they bet it must minus the bet amount and when they win it should add the bet amount and the amount won

Comment: Yeah all you need to do is store the amount they started with which is 100 i assume and then minus from chipsNow-100 in your report method

Comment: Okay i got it, Im assuming the professor only wants to output the amount won that Is more than what the user originally had for chips which is 100

Comment: I'm glad you got it working man and thats simple to change as you need if its wrong

Comment: but now because we subtracted 100, it is giving a negative output.  So for example user loses 20 from 100 which will be 80.  They didn't gain anything, it's giving me an output of -100, and I want it to just output 0 and say they didn't earn anything

Comment: Well that doesn't make sense 80 - 100 should give you -20...   also you can simple do and if statement which checks if the chips amount is greater than 0, then they won X amount or if it's less than 0 that means they lost X amount

Comment: Hahaha programming is always fun. Glad it's working